# How do you map Touch Joysticks in Bluestack?

Tags: windows, bluestacks

Ive been trying to setup Bluestack so I can play my phone Terraria saves on my computer with a mouse and keyboard. I own the PC version as well but I just want to use my Pc to renovate a big house as it should be faster with a keyboard and mouse. Ive found Aurora 2 and it was helpful but it has no more description on how to do more complicated inputs then bluestack itself. I've made one setup and it kinda works so I get the just I just don't undersatand a few small details. My current config file looks like this:

```
#Terraria
#Aurora 2 keymapping tool

[origin]
Author = Dracrius
Rating = Label2

[keys]
W = Tap (8,69)
S = Tap (8,92)
D = Tap (14,80)
A = Tap (1,80)
P = Tap (98,3)
Z = Tap (47,5)
1 = Tap (3,5)

[guidance]
W = 
S = 
D = 
A = 
P = 
Z = 
1 = 

[gamepad]
LeftStick_Up = W
LeftStick_Down = S
LeftStick_Left = A
LeftStick_Right = D
Y = Z
B = 1
A = 1

[opensensor]
Mode = Touch1
```

Now it all works and i can switch items or pause but is i try to use the dpad to walk left and down work because it's the edge of the screen but up and right do not. They both just center the joystick where i set the up and right buttons to. Now I know this is because of how the terraria touch stick works. You have to touch the screen for the joysticks to even show up (where ever you touch) and then drag in the direction you'd like to move. So how do I tell Bluestack to treat it as such? I know lots of touch games use this style of onscreen control so it should be do able but I can't find a description on how or any of the finer details of bluestack key mapping. These are parts of the Template bluestack gives you that I think may be related or I don't understand enough to know!

```
[OpenSensor]

#
# First, specify a mode for the app.
#
#Mode   = TapA          *Tap vs Touch?* 
#Mode   = TapB          *What's the difference?*
#Mode   = Touch1
#Mode   = Touch2        *What's the difference?*
#Mode   = Touch1TapA    *What does this mean?*
#Mode   = Touch1TapB    *What's the difference?*
#Mode   = Swipe
#Mode   = Tilt
#Mode   = TiltTapA      *What's TiltTap?*
#Mode   = TiltTapB      *What's the difference?*
#Mode   = TiltTouch1    *What's TiltTouch?*

#
# Specify mode specific guidance.   *WHATTT?*
#
#Tilt       = STilt
#SwipeTap   = SSwipeTap                     *Maybe this has something to do with it!*
#Area1      = (0,33,100,33)     STouchArea  *I think this has something to do with it!*
```